# Possibility of exporting a complete android project into iOS in react native

Tags: react-native

I am planning to learn react native but i don't have any MacOS device, and i have read that even when using react native, iOS apps can only be developed using xcode.

So is it possible to develop a complete react native app in android and later transfer it to MacOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is written completely in react native (IE javascript) it should be relatively easy to compile it for Ios later. The may be some differences in components needed and props that are only available for one system or the other.

If your app depends on some natively linked libraries, then you should ensure they have support for both ios as well as android.

Since you are learning React Native, if you build using the expo platform, then it is even more likely it can run on both. Expo also has an online emulator for ios and android.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt and a quick reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can't develop 'pure' React Native for iOS on Windows. **Normally** you need xcode and therefor a macOS. But you can use the [Expo SDK](https://docs.expo.io):

> [...] That means you don't need to use Xcode or Android Studio, or write any native code, and it also makes your pure-JS project very portable because it can run in any native environment containing the Expo SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and a quick reply.